# Positioning of form elements

Tags: css

I have three form elements which I want to position next to each other.

```
form.left
{
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
}

form.right
{
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
}

form.center
{
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
}
```

Is it possible to position them next to each other horizontally and if it is what kind of positioning should I use? The elements should be 20px (the padding) above the container border.

This is the code for my container in which the forms should fit in:

```
#container
{
    width:1010px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#999999;
    border-radius:14px;
    padding:20px;
    border:3px #43b2e6;
    border-style:groove;
}
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle demo?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by two ways:

**1st  Way**

```
<body> 
 <div id="header"> 
   <h1>Header</h1> 
 </div> 
 <div id="left"> 
  Port side text... 
 </div> 
 <div id="right"> 
   Starboard side text... 
 </div> 
 <div id="middle"> 
  Middle column text... 
 </div> 
 <div id="footer"> 
 Footer text... 
 </div> 
</body>
```

And here's the **CSS** code:

```
body { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; } 
div#header { clear: both; height: 50px; background-color: aqua; padding: 1px; }
div#left { float: left; width: 150px; background-color: red; } 
div#right { float: right; width: 150px; background-color: green; } 
div#middle { padding: 0px 160px 5px 160px; margin: 0px; background-color: silver;}
div#footer { clear: both; background-color: yellow; }
```

**2nd Way**

```
<div id="container">
 <div class="leftside" style="float: left;">Left Stuff</div>
 <div class="middleside" style="float: left;">Middle Stuff</div>
 <div class="rightside" style="float: left;">Right Stuff</div>
 <br style="clear: left;" />
</div>
```

use below css:

```
    .leftside
    {
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    }

   .middleside
    {
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    }

    .rightside
    {
    width:200px;
    height:450px;
    background-color:#000000;
    padding:10px 40px; 
    }

    #container
    {
    width:1010px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#999999;
    border-radius:14px;
    padding:20px;
    border:3px #43b2e6;
    border-style:groove;
    }
```

Comment: please consider posting properly formatted code and some explanation of your answers too!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you have just 3 form fields which you are trying to align side by side, use the following code:

```
<table style="font-family: Calibri; font-size: small">
    <tr height="15" style="height:11.25pt">
        <td height="15" style="height:11.25pt;width:42pt" width="56" class="style3">
            Label 1</td>
        <td style="width:42pt" width="56">
            <input id="Text1" type="text" class="style2" /></td>
        <td style="width:42pt" width="56" class="style3">
            Label 2</td>
        <td style="width:42pt" width="56">
            <input id="Text2" type="text" class="style2" /></td>
        <td style="width:42pt" width="56" class="style3">
            Label 3</td>
        <td style="width:42pt" width="56">
            <input id="Text3" type="text" class="style2" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```